# Missing "statistics" from video list response

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am calling youtube api for videos.list(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with part="snippet,contentDetails,status,statistics,topicDetails". On Apr 6 or 7 2017 something changed and for many videos I don't get field "statistics". I'm wondering, why this happens and how I can get publicly available counts, like viewCount, for them?
Here are a couple of example videos: PiZEMoZ535I,vHw_drm5cRk

Comment: Don't have an answer I'm afraid, but I'm also seeing the same problem.

Comment: I have noticed that the videos where the statistics object is missing have publicStatsViewable set to False (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.publicStatsViewable).

I can't find anything in the docs to say that the statistics object would be missing in that case, but it seems a one-to-one correlation thus far.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but I can't access the Issue tracker linked by Vitor Costa. I tried to use the [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) now and passing the parameter `part=statistics` and the `videoId`. And I get a 200 successful response. Here is the [request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=statistics&id=unAwziX-tsA&_h=1&) that I am doing. So it seems that it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug, it was working fine until April 7th. There's an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37107133) created for that, however Google still didn't say anything about this.

EDIT:
This seems to finally be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to the API with the resource video.list with parameters :
    part: statistics
    id: "id of the video found in previous request"

If you have more than one video id you can specify the id of videos with a comma-separated list like :

```
id: "Xxsdw6zG1bg, Xxsdw6zG1bg,...." )
```

The request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videospart=statistics&id=UHdgXkkVyl0%2C+Xxsdw6zG1bg&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The response will be like this :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/rxvjZzq2nNqBg7Me5VQv1ToZm64\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 2,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/3fah-cngFxFOnytseMYZU1TK_-8\"",
   "id": "UHdgXkkVyl0",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3070836",
    "likeCount": "72140",
    "dislikeCount": "1132",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "7798"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"MmqJLb8ZBOWRQIsg7xej7lrKLMI/J4xM7Dd23TGYU6on-PESyEIAE9A\"",
   "id": "Xxsdw6zG1bg",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "131487",
    "likeCount": "1459",
    "dislikeCount": "25",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "39"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

And you have the statistics !

Comment: Yes, now it works. It was actually a bug that they fixed in a few days. Thanks.