# Response is missing requested part for some video ids

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are facing a problem where the YouTube Data API isn't returning the statistics for some requested videos. We use a custom implementation to interact with the API, but the problem can be reproduced with the API explorer, which I will use throughout this post.

---

First, I'll show you what happens with a working channel ID (`UCfDUwK9MPrjxmsTz1pzjkbw`):

Using [`channels.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with `part=statistics,contentDetails,snippet` and `id=UCfDUwK9MPrjxmsTz1pzjkbw` we get a valid response. For this use case we are interested in `contentDetails -> relatedPlaylists -> uploads`, which returns the playlist ID `UUfDUwK9MPrjxmsTz1pzjkbw`.

[`playlistItems.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with `part=contentDetails` and `playlistId=UUfDUwK9MPrjxmsTz1pzjkbw` (the playlist ID we found in the step before) returns a list of videos that are part of the playlist. We are interested in `contentDetails -> videoId`. For example `vSS9AYF29_U`.

[`videos.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=id,statistics` and `id=vSS9AYF29_U` (the example video ID from the step before) we get the response we are looking for (the statistics for this video).

---

Now, the same process with a channel ID that fails to produce the desired result (`UCpHTv1eQBeSlrdmlh8C6ZxQ`):

[`channels.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) returns the playlist ID `UUpHTv1eQBeSlrdmlh8C6ZxQ`

[`playlistItems.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) returns the example video ID `OFTib3gUua0`

[`videos.List`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) does **not** return the requested statistics part.

---

Has anyone an idea why this happens? What makes this channel so special? Can the owner of the channel disable public information being retrieved via the API? The statistics themselves can be seen if you watch the video in your browser (https://youtu.be/OFTib3gUua0).

I don't think the problem is with our implementation because it can be reproduced with the API explorer. Another weird thing is that this worked a couple of days ago for every channel ID we used.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: There's another case of someone noticing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339723/missing-statistics-from-video-list-response


 
I have noticed that the videos where the statistics object is missing have publicStatsViewable set to False (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.publicStatsViewable). I can't find anything in the docs to say that the statistics object would be missing in that case, but it seems a one-to-one correlation thus far - and I believe that that publicStatsViewable is something that the channel-owner can set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user3468054! The docs say "statistics like a video's viewcount and ratings will still be publicly visible even if this property's value is set to false." This contradicts the behaviour though, since `part=statistics` returns `viewCount, likeCount, dislikeCount, favoriteCount, commentCount`

Comment: I agree it doesn't really hang together with what the docs say - just an empirical observation (on a small sample)!
See also: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37107133

Comment: Don't see any problem at the moment. However there has been a few people saying that "random" content has not been working. Probably a bug while they are doing something on the back end.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a bug, it was working fine until April 7th. There's an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37107133) created for that, we are still waiting for Google's response on that.

EDIT:
This seems to finally be fixed